# MATLAB - Can I make my handle object behave like a graphics handle?

Tags: arrays, matlab, oop, object, handle

With graphics handles, you can do this:

```
>> a = nan(1,5)

a =
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN

>> a(3) = line([1 2],[1 2])

a =
       NaN       NaN    0.0042       NaN       NaN

>> find(~isnan(a),1,'first')

ans =
     3
```

If this is done with a normal handle-derived class, this error happens:

```
>> a(3) = MyObject(1,1,1)
The following error occurred converting from MyObject to double:
Error using double
Conversion to double from MyObject is not possible.
```

As far as I understand, graphics handles are just doubles. Can custom objects also behave this way?

Comment: related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6806344/97160, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2510427/97160

Comment: These posts do not answer the question I am asking, which has to do specifically with being able to find(~isnan(x))

Comment: @BBrock: perhaps the cell-array example I posted can help, you would use `~cellfun(@isempty, a)` instead of ISNAN to test for non-empty cells

Comment: @Amro: Thanks for the suggestion--I know I can use cell arrays for this purpose, but it would be particularly convenient for me to have functionality identical to the functionality offered by graphics handles...so I'm kind of guessing at this point that this is not possible?

Comment: @BBrock: I'm afraid that's not possible, you cannot make your class return objects as numeric handles. You should be aware that handle graphics (HG) are not implemented using the documented [MCOS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html) class system, rather using the older and completely undocumented UDD classes: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/introduction-to-udd/

Comment: this seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298859/extending-matlab-uicontrol

Comment: Thank you, UDD/MCOS class information answers my question. Well I'm sad that I can't really do what I wanted to, but your alternatives are valid. I will accept your answer but can you edit it to include the information in this comment? Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

#### MyObject.m

```
classdef MyObject < handle
    properties
        x
    end
    methods
        function obj = MyObject(x)
            if nargin < 1, x = NaN; end
            obj.x = x;
        end
    end
end
```

#### MATLAB

```
>> a = MyObject.empty(0,3)
a = 
  0x3 MyObject array with properties:

    x

>> a(3) = MyObject(10)
a = 
  1x3 MyObject array with properties:

    x

>> a(3)
ans = 
  MyObject with properties:

    x: 10
>> a(1)
ans = 
  MyObject with properties:

    x: NaN
```

Note that the objects `a(1:2)` were constructed by calling the default constructor with no arguments.

An alternative way:

```
>> a = cell(1,3)
a = 
    []    []    []
>> a{3} = MyObject(10)
a = 
    []    []    [1x1 MyObject]
```

---

Note: handle graphics (HG) are not implemented using the documented [MCOS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html) class system, rather using the older and completely undocumented [UDD](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/introduction-to-udd) classes.